# Is the Sputik Kernel Project only for Dell Xps 13?

Tags: dell, xps, ultrabook, sputnik

I read that Dell Sputnik Kernel is necessary for the correct usage of the hardware in dell xps 13 ultrabook and xps 15 ultrabook. Do you know if the dell sputnik kernel is necessary on Dell XPS 14 ultrabook? As all this laptop  should have  similar hardware.

A.